# Webrisk and google save browsing API return different result than google transparency site status. Unsafe sites returned safe

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-webrisk

I run a site that displays a lot of images from users from external URLs. Recently we got a warning for some image URLs which are apparently flagged "unsafe" from Google Save Browsing, which provokes a brutal red error message for all users.

The issue is that the entire site gets blocked as unsafe and of course, users think this is our own site and not the external image URL only.

After some research, we found the Google safe browsing API and Google Webrisk and build our tool on top of it to check each image URL against their APIs.

The issue is that the results are CLEAN for URLs that are UNSAFE found by the https://transparencyreport.google.com/?

I am not sure what we are doing wrong in this case since the APIs seem senseless if they do not report the same URLs unsafe which the transparency report declares unsafe.

Does anyone have similar issues? How can I check if google finds an image URL safe other than using those to APIs from them?

How could I display those external images without getting the ugly warnings from google?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will be extremely useful if you could share either the URL for your site or screenshots for the "unsafe" blocking message.

I would start by checking [here](https://cloud.google.com/web-risk/docs/user-warnings) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/web-risk/docs/advisory).

Or maybe [request a review](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6347750#request_review)

Comment: I did not want to post here a link to a potential bad page but this would be an example "opensea.profilesetting.in/logo.gif" just add the https:// before again. I wanted to avoid anyone clicking this link. WARNING this is a real BAD link. don't use it other than to test. In the transparency report site, this link is flagged, but neither in Safe Browsing nor WebRisk this URL gets back negative. I feel those APIs are useless if they are not equal reliable as transparency reports. thx in advance for some light on this.

Comment: Did you request a review?

Comment: Why would I request a review? The review process is for site owners to request a review if they are blocked for the wrong reasons. this is not my case. It isnt my site which is blocked. I code a platform that displays millions of images from third-party URLs and google blocks some of those URLs based on the same results of the transparency report site. To avoid such issues we implemented Webrisk and tested with Save Browsing API which both don't report the same URLs as a problem. In other words the Safe Browsing API and Webrisk seem useless because they don't work correct.

Comment: Fair enough!
I hope the rest of the information was helpful.